# MalformedParameterizedTypeException when use ArrayList<ArrayList<>>

Tags: groovy

Here is my code:

```
class TestDraft {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String, Double>> a = []

    static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDraft().a.add(["pr", 2])
    }
}
```

It raise:

> "java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException"

when I change `ArrayList<ArrayList<String, Double>>` to `ArrayList` it work, but I hope to what cause:

> MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Comment: What do you think `ArrayList<Integer, Integer, Integer>` mean?

Comment: Is it `java` or `groovy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer, Integer, Integer>>
```

doesn't make any sense (which I think is what the error is telling you)

It should just be:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

To say that you have a list of lists of integers...  Generics do not express how many elements are in a List

Comment: I update my question, when i use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String, Double>>`, it raise same error, why?

Comment: maybe I know, ArrayList has not syntax `ArrayList<String, Double>`, it only has `ArrayList<Type>`, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's it :-)